# What's the recommended way to set networkaddress.cache.ttl in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I need to set Java's DNS cache TTL (networkaddress.cache.ttl) for an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk app running in Tomcat 8.  Because EB can start and stop server instances at any time, I can't simply edit a Tomcat config file and the server and expect the change to persist.

I tried setting the networkaddress.cache.ttl and sun.net.inetaddr.ttl environment variables, but those had no effect.  Amazon says calling `java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");` "will not work if you run your application inside of Tomcat" (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4035).  What's a good way to set the TTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that I was doing it wrong.  Setting the sun.net.inetaddr.ttl environment variable works.  You can do this in your Elastic Beakstalk config file:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
      option_name: sun.net.inetaddr.ttl
      value: 60
```

60 seconds is the value [recommended by Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html)

Another option that seems a little nicer to me is to create and use a java.security file:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
      option_name: java.security.properties
      value: /etc/myapp/java.security
container_commands:
    00create_config_dir:
        command: 'mkdir -p /etc/myapp'
        ignoreErrors: true
    01create_java_security_file:
        command: 'echo "networkaddress.cache.ttl=60" > /etc/myapp/java.security'
        ignoreErrors: true
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can define a @Configuration

```
@Configuration
class SecurityManager {
    
init { 
  Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "5")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring framework, following is what I did to set the `networkaddress.cache.ttl` at the time of application initialisation.

1. Define a new Java class as follows.

   ```
   package com.example.util;
   public class SecurityManager {
     public SecurityManager() {
       java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");
     }
   }
   ```
2. Ask spring framework to instantiate the object of above class as a singleton at the time on spring container creation.

   ```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

     <bean id="securityManager" 
       class="com.example.util.SecurityManager" scope="singleton" />

   </beans>
   ```

Comment: Do you know what is the default value for Java 8 running on Elastic BeanStalk? I cant seem to find it @monish001

Comment: i created a @ Configuration class that sets these properties, but from the logs it seems that HikariPool-1 - Start completed. starts before setting the properties. Would that be a problem? Does that count as an interaction with the database?