# Elastic Beanstalk, Java Spring Boot and RDS Multi AZ Deployment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

We are about to deploy a Spring Boot 2.3 Application on Elastic Beanstalk running Java 8 (Not Corretto 8).
We are thinking of using Multi AZ for the RDS and i am reading the Readme for that
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html
and there is a part which states that we should be aware of the DNS cache in case of fail over
`Setting the JVM TTL for DNS name lookups`
which says the following thing

```
The default TTL can vary according to the version of your JVM and whether a
 security manager is installed. 
Many JVMs provide a default TTL less than 60 seconds. 
If you're using such a JVM and not using a security manager, 
you can ignore the rest of this topic. For more information on security managers 
in Oracle, see The security manager in the Oracle documentation.
```

What is the default value of Java 8 In Elastic Beanstalk? I can't seem to find it.
Also from my understanding if the ttl  value is big, and a fail happens on the database, it won't fail over to the instance in the other AZ because DNS won't change. Is that correct?
Also is the default value is too big, what is the Spring Boot way of setting that property without using XML files ?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579589/whats-the-recommended-way-to-set-networkaddress-cache-ttl-in-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

You can tune this in the JVM with code like:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "1");
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl" , "1");
```

This value is the number of seconds to cache the data.

However, you may also want to consider [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-proxy-now-generally-available/) as it can speed up failover.  There should be no code changes, only configuration changes.  There is no additional cost for RDS Proxy.

Comment: Where to put those setProperty calls? Also do you have any idea what would be the default value for Elasticbeanstalk?

Comment: That code needs to be in your code before you interact with a database, perhaps in a `@PostConstruct` or through an `ApplicationListener`.  And no, I don't know the default but you can find it by getting the above properties.  A bit of a pain though.

Comment: i created a @Configuration class that sets these properties, but from the logs it seems that `HikariPool-1 - Start completed.` starts before setting the properties. Would that be a problem? Does that count as an interaction with the database?